# Is there any replacement of ctl+a to move the curser to the left most in screen

Tags: command-line

it's hassle to move the curser to the beginning in terminal, because using screen ,the key combination ctl+a is set to active the screen selection hot key.

Anyone know how to solve this or work around or better way to move the curser to the beginning of the line?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In screen just use CTRL-A followed by A to go to the beginning of the line.  Takes a little getting used to but sort of makes sense.

Comment: By answer such questions it encourages them to be asked where they shouldn't be. SO is for questions relating to programming.

Comment: I would never of guessed you were 38. You sound like a 10 year old kid.

Comment: @par thanks for answering my newbie question, it helps a lot, could you tell me how could I get this information except google, man maybe a way to go, but it's to tedious to read the whole thing to find out the simple solution like your answer.